# How do I run tests for a single model using mocha/mean.js?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, meanjs

I've been looking into mean.js testing.  There's a grunt test task that runs all app with a single and easy `grunt test`, but I don't want to run all tests everytime.

I've installed mocha globally, and want to run tests for a single model using it, but doing...

```
mocha 'app/tests/mymodelname.server.model.js'
```

Throws me back a

> "MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model
>   MyModelName"

What would be the easiest way to run single tests for the server?

Thanks!

D

Comment: That error occurs when a (Mongoose) model is being used without having first registered the schema for it. I don't know MEAN.js, but you probably need to load the model initialization code into your test file before you use/test your models.

Comment: yea, that's what I imagine, but it should be a way to doing this without modifying all my test files.

Comment: Mocha has a `-r/--require` command line option that you may be able to use to load the database initialization module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As robertklep mentioned, the best way to do this is by using the --require option in mocha to require server.js file (which includes all the required initialization for database module and additional stuff).

So in this case if you are running a mean.js app, the right way to do it would be:

```
mocha 'app/tests/mymodelname.server.model.js' -r server.js
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Previous replies are completely correct, there's a mongoose loader that is defined within grunt and passed into the 'grunt test' task.  Take a look at **gruntfile.js**:`grunt.registerTask('test', ['env:test', 'mongoose', 'mochaTest', 'karma:unit']);`

I've looked around for nice solutions to this, and there should be a '--grep' switch to use with Mocha, but getting it passed in through grunt is beyond my current skillset - suggestions welcome!

I'm sure there's a really great way to do this, but for now I've just restricted the test file configuration list when wanting to work with just one test.  I've modified '**config\assets\test.js**' to point to just one file.  It's not pretty, and I'll probably get burned for suggesting it, but it works for me right now.